# How to remove duplicates from correlation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, data-manipulation

I have some problems with my result:

```
dataCorr = data.corr(method='pearson')
dataCorr = dataCorr[abs(dataCorr) >= 0.7].stack().reset_index()
dataCorr = dataCorr[dataCorr.level_0!=dataCorr.level_1]
```

From my correlation matrix:

```
dataCorr = data.corr(method='pearson')
```

I convert this matrix to columns:

```
dataCorr = dataCorr[abs(dataCorr) >= 0.7].stack().reset_index()
```

And after I remove diagonal line of matrix:

```
dataCorr = dataCorr[dataCorr.level_0!=dataCorr.level_1]
```

But I still have duplicate pairs

```
level_0             level_1             0
LiftPushSpeed       RT1EntranceSpeed    0.881714
RT1EntranceSpeed    LiftPushSpeed       0.881714
```

How avoid this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert lower triangle of values to `NaN`s and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) remove it:

```
np.random.seed(12)

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(5,6)))
print (data)
    0   1   2  3   4   5
0  11   6  17  2   3   3
1  12  16  17  5  13   2
2  11  10   0  8  12  13
3  18   3   4  3   1   0
4  18  18  16  6  13   9

dataCorr = data.corr(method='pearson')
dataCorr = dataCorr.mask(np.tril(np.ones(dataCorr.shape)).astype(np.bool))
print (dataCorr)
    0         1         2         3         4         5
0 NaN  0.042609 -0.041656 -0.113998 -0.173011 -0.201122
1 NaN       NaN  0.486901  0.567216  0.914260  0.403469
2 NaN       NaN       NaN -0.412853  0.157747 -0.354012
3 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.823628  0.858918
4 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.635730
5 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

#in your data change 0.5 to 0.7
dataCorr = dataCorr[abs(dataCorr) >= 0.5].stack().reset_index()
print (dataCorr)
   level_0  level_1         0
0        1        3  0.567216
1        1        4  0.914260
2        3        4  0.823628
3        3        5  0.858918
4        4        5  0.635730
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.tril(np.ones(dataCorr.shape)))
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you have removed the diagonal elements, I am afraid that's all your code is going to do at the moment.

In order to tackle the duplicate problem across, I have concatenated the two columns after sorting and then filtered out duplicates, removing the concatenated column afterwards.

Here is a complete example -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

dataCorr = data.corr(method='pearson')
dataCorr = dataCorr[abs(dataCorr) >= 0.01].stack().reset_index()
dataCorr = dataCorr[dataCorr['level_0'].astype(str)!=dataCorr['level_1'].astype(str)]

# filtering out lower/upper triangular duplicates 
dataCorr['ordered-cols'] = dataCorr.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(sorted([x['level_0'],x['level_1']])),axis=1)
dataCorr = dataCorr.drop_duplicates(['ordered-cols'])
dataCorr.drop(['ordered-cols'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(dataCorr)
```

Comment: nice its good i think when matrix is not diogonal (mixed) thnx